# Fixing Inconsistent query behaviour between datastax driver and cqlsh

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

```
String cql = "SELECT * FROM myks.tbl WHERE bid=? AND mid<? LIMIT ? ORDER BY mid DESC ALLOW FILTERING";
```

If I execute this in cqlsh, it works fine, with or without ALLOW FILTERING appended. If I execute this from the latest (2.1.1) datastax driver I get

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING

It clearly works from the command line, so doesn't that mean it should work from the driver. What to do?

Comment: Is there an option from the statement or prepared statement to enable filtering?

Comment: @AlexWhite That was a provocative question... ;-) [DataStax Driver](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/Select.html)

Comment: @Eddie B  QueryBuilder.select().all().from("myks","tbl").where(QueryBuilder.eq("bid",bid)).and(QueryBuilder.lt("mid", mid)).limit(limit).orderBy(QueryBuilder.desc("mid")).allowFiltering(); gives the same resulting error msg.

Comment: Can you share your table definition

Comment: Any solution for this? I am getting the same error? Is allowFiltering() allowed via the Jdbc driver?